# get array with most similar data

Tags: java

I am trying to obtain among several arrays the one that has the most similar values, that is, the one that has the least unequal numbers between them. This is my program:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BuscarArrayMasParecido {

 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int totalDeCadaArray=15;
    int mediaDeCadaArray=totalDeCadaArray/3;
    int[] a1 =   {1, 3, 11};
    int[] a2 =   {1, 4, 10};
    int[] a3 =   {1, 6, 8};
    int[] a4 =   {2, 4, 9};
    int[] a5 =   {1, 5, 9};
    int[] a6 =   {2, 3, 10};
  
    ArrayList<int[]> a = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> sumasDiferencias= new ArrayList();
    a.add(a1);a.add(a2);a.add(a3);a.add(a4);a.add(a5);a.add(a6);
    
    for(int[] n:a)
    {
        int sumaDiferecias=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
        {
           int diferencia = abs(n[i]-mediaDeCadaArray);
           sumaDiferecias+=diferencia;
        }
        sumasDiferencias.add(sumaDiferecias);
    }
    
    for(int[]n:a)
    {
        int sumaDiferencias=0;
        for (int i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
        {
            int diferencia = abs(n[i]-mediaDeCadaArray);
            sumaDiferencias+=diferencia;           
        }
        if (sumaDiferencias==minimo(sumasDiferencias))
        {
            printArray(n);
        }
    }
}
    
    public static void printArray(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static int minimo(ArrayList<Integer> diferencias)
    {
        int min = diferencias.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < diferencias.size(); i++) 
        {
            if (diferencias.get(i) < min) {
                min = diferencias.get(i);
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
    
}
```

It returns me these three arrays as a result:

```
[1,6,8]
[2,4,9]
[1,5,9]
```

to obtain them, what I do is calculate the differences between each element of the array and the average of all of them (they all add up to 15 and are 3 elements). Then add those differences and choose the ones with the smallest sum of the differences from the average. And I get those three arrays which is not what I want since the array with the most similar values is the middle one (`[2,4,9]`). It is the one that is best distributed of all. The objective of the program is to distribute inheritances in such a way that each number represents the value of an asset and they must be distributed as equitably as possible. I wanted to know how I can get the array with the most similar values.

Comment: All three arrays output by your program have equal distributions as defined by your specification of sum of differences from average. So what is your problem?

Comment: Please explain a bit more why you think that `[2,4,9]` is a better fit than the other 2. The metric you have described here is indeed equal for them, so it is unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: in arrays 1 and 3, the first heir is more affected than the other two heirs.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is the sum of squares of differences, instead of just the sum of differences? That would give you `[2,4,9]` as the answer.

Comment: What is the exact formula? Because I am using this: sum(xi-mean)² and it gives me the series as a result:  {1,5,9}

Comment: You say you're using the formula `sum(xi-mean)²` but in fact you're not, `sumaDiferecias+=diferencia;` means `sum(xi-mean)`. You are not squaring the difference.

Comment: You'll need something like `sumaCuadradosDiferencias += (diferencia * diferencia);`